# Retrieve Archive Delay on Openfire, how about Ejabberd?

Tags: openfire, ejabberd

I am using Openfire server with Strophe and it has the Monitoring Plugin installed. It archives my messages, and I use `strophe` to load them. But there is a 30seconds-1min delay for the messages to be put into the database.

I am wondering, if I use Ejabberd to archive messages, and the messages get put into the database, is there a delay as well?

Comment: Is there a delay on retrieving the messages or putting the messages into the database ?

Comment: When its putting into the db there is about 5seconds to 1 min delay, it depends. But apparently the guy who wrote the plugin put the delay on purpose, incase if there are lots of archive messages getting written into the DB, which might cause a bottle neck... i assume. So totally no delay on Ejabbered?? I am just a little worried if its a lot harder to set up and if its easy to use like openfire...

Comment: As I tested all this with ejabberd, I didn't faced any delay while retrieving the messages and putting the messages into the database. It might take some nano or micro seconds to put into database but not about 1 minute. And while retrieving, I am sure there is no delay in my POC app.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks, from the other thread, the only reason i am tempted to switch over to Ejabberd is because of this - the delay for Archiving, because i am building an App required to have no data stored on the device, i need to use Archive to pull the history on each app startup. And if there is a delay it means some message might be lost. So i might have to switch over to Ejabberd. Does Ejabberd come with an Interface(Admin Panel)? And how do you install the modules like Archive? I have totally no knowledge about Ejabberd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no delay on the ejabberd. As I was working on retrieving the messages using ejabberd, I didn't found any delay while retrieving the messages and even while putting in the database. It might take some nano or micro seconds to put in database but while retrieving I am sure there is no delay in my POC app.

I worked with Ejabberd and its pretty awesome. I don't know much about openfire and I really suggest you to switch over to Ejabberd.

Ejabberd has an Admin panel which shows online users, virtual hosts, nodes, modules and lots of stuff which admin can access atmost. Its pretty much easier for [Installation](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/) and [Configuration](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/). Ejabberd is actively developed and widely used.

Ejabberd supports all the messaging features. While installation all the modules will be installed. If you want to install some external module (not developed by Ejabberd Official people), then go through with that module installation docs. Some of the modules which are developed by Ejabberd wont get installed while ejabberd setup. Take a look [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib) for those modules. You can install these modules as:

```
ejabberdctl module_update_specs
ejabberdctl module_install <module_name>
```

After installing the module, just enable that module at `modules` section in the ejabberd configuration file.

Comment: Sweet, that sounds like pretty easy to install, i might give it a try, so all those offline messages, archive are all official modules? And 1 big reason i want to switch is cos the big guys like Whatsapp etc uses Ejabberd. I just chose Openfire to start because its in Java, and i am familiar with it, Erlang seems scary to me.

Comment: @John Yes. All those modules are official. And don't even worry about erlang language. If you wanna start with erlang it's pretty much easier to learn. If you don't want to learn, then no problem. You dont get a chance to debug the erlang and ejabberd code. Incase, if you get any problem, there is a lot of online support regarding ejabberd and erlang. So dont panic

Comment: @John And even you can reach out with their [github](https://github.com/processone/) to check the latest release of ejabberd. you can find their active development there. And please dont forgot the answer acceptance. If you found solution, then be sure to accept for sake of other users who are having same question.