# Ejabberd sbin/ejabberdctl start(No such file or directory)

Tags: ejabberd

When i was installing Ejabberd, it gave an error saying it wasnt installed successfully. But then i have the folder my-ejabberd with all the folders in it.

I am not sure if thats 100% installed, but when i try to start up the server, with the command line sbin/ejabberdctl start, it says No such file or directory. I am running on Mac OS 10.8.5.

Not sure what the problem is. Any Ideas?

Edit

This is the error from Terminal

bin/ejabberdctl: line 24: getent: command not found
/Users/clark/my-ejabberd/bin/erl: line 35: /Applications/my-ejabberd/bin/erlexec: No such file or directory

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Did you see `sbin` folder in `my-ejabberd` and `ejabberdctl` in `sbin` folder ? If you see it, then make sure your present working directory in terminal is my-ejabberd.. If ejabberd doesn't installed successfully, then you cant see the my-ejabberd folder though.

Comment: Hii! I see a bin folder, but not a sbin folder, and i see the ejabberdctl in the bin folder, also see start, status, stop etc in the bin. I tried running 'bin/ejabberdctl start' it says no such file or directory. If i install it the first time, when i try to run it and it will say node already running, but if i restart the computer, then i will have the error i put above in the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have installed the ejabberd with [source code](http://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/install-osx/) then `ejabberdctl` will be sbin folder. If installed from source code, follow this:

```
$ cd /path/to/my-ejabberd
$ sbin/ejabberdctl start
$ sbin/ejabberdctl status
The node ejabberd@localhost is started with status: started
ejabberd 15.06.21 is running in that node
```

If you have installed with [binary installer](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads), then you will see the `ejabberdctl` in bin folder. And also you see start, stop and some other commands. If you did this, then follow

```
$ cd /path/to/my-ejabberd
$ cd bin
$ ./ejabberdctl start
$ ./ejabberdctl status
The node ejabberd@localhost is started with status: started
ejabberd 15.06.21 is running in that node
```

If you see the node is starting, then the ejabberd is running successfully. If you want you can check http://localhost:5280/admin for the ejabberd admin panel interface. To access this admin panel you need to register a user and give admin access in the ejabberd configuration file as:

```
// If installed from source code
$ sbin/ejabberdctl register username localhost password

// If installed from binary installer
$ ./ejabberdctl register username localhost password
```

Then open the ejabberd configuration file (ejabberd.yml) and add username under the admin as:

```
acl:  
  admin:
    - "username": "localhost"
```

Now restart the server or stop and start the server and open the admin panel. Give username and password then you can access the [admin panel](http://localhost:5280/admin).

[image]

Comment: I have finally installed it, their Binary installer has bug, so it wont finish the post installation linking process. But i am not sure how to install modules on it/ or Virtual Machine. I opened the localhost:5280/admin and it only has 1 tab which is virtual hosts on it and nothing else.

Comment: @John I have updated the answer with the admin panel screenshot. Your admin panel screenshot should look like that. And in your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266857/retrieve-archive-delay-on-openfire-how-about-ejabberd/32272333#32272333), I have explained you how to install the modules. First thing you need to go through the [ejabberd docs](http://docs.ejabberd.im/) very well. so that you will understand how to handle ejabberd stuff. And their binary installer doesn't have any bug, right now i have installed through binary installer and it works fine for me.

Comment: Yer i have no idea, it said post installation failed, and some folder wasnt installed. But i can login on localhost:5280, but mine looks different, it doesnt have the tabs that you have. I put the pic in the edit above.

Comment: @John Ok. Better install it again through binary installer and run it. That's weird problem for you and I am confused. Try to install it again and let me know through my mail: yashwanthbabu.gujarathi@gmail.com

Comment: I think i got it to work!! But just one extra question, for the mod_mam and mod_ping(to disconnect idle users?)  they didnt come with the install right? I have to install them? From the modules-overview? Or if there are any Guides for it. I have a lot of modules now, can send receive messages etc but just dont have the ping and mam module.

Comment: @John You can add them directly. They will be installed but not enabled in the configuration file. No need to install `mod_ping` and `mod_mam`. You can just add them and restart the ejabberd server. You can find the installable modules in this [repo](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib). Apart from these modules, remaining all the modules were already been installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88381/discussion-between-yashwanth-and-john).

Comment: I can't able to register user each time getting `Error: cannot_register`. can you guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case installing with .dmg  i found using `find / -name ejabberdctl` in terminal and result `/Applications/ejabberd.xx.x/bin/ejabberdctl`