# Linux server xmpp ejabberd start ,status not running?

Tags: ubuntu, server, xmpp, cpanel, ejabberd

I'm using server with SSH access. I'm trying to install ejabberd with command but it is not working. I manage to install it without sudo. For installing i follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288866/ejabberd-sbin-ejabberdctl-startno-such-file-or-directory/32300202#32300202).

now main problem in running ejabberd,Errors while starting ejabberd:

```
$ ./ejabberdctl start
/home/sancm/ejabberd/bin/erl: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/home/sancm/ejabberd/bin/erl: fork: Cannot allocate memory

$ ./ejabberdctl status
./ejabberdctl: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/home/sanchr5m/ejabberd/bin/erl: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/home/sanchr5m/ejabberd/bin/erl: fork: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
./ejabberdctl: line 125: 3009909 Aborted 
"$@"
```

On my server apt-get and sudo, su are not working. I don't know why.

```
free -m

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32043      29812       2230         19       3624      10701
-/+ buffers/cache:      15486      16556
Swap:         4095       1405       2690
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need root access to install and start ejabberd. Try this:

```
$ ./configure --enable-user --prefix=/tmp/aa
$ make
$ make install
$ cd /tmp/aa
$ ./sbin/ejabberdctl live
...
13:02:34.457 [info] ejabberd 18.04.71 is started in the node ejabberd@localhost in 5.67s
13:02:34.459 [info] Application ejabberd started on node ejabberd@localhost
13:02:34.459 [info] Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5280 for ejabberd_http
13:02:34.460 [info] Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5269 for ejabberd_s2s_in
13:02:34.460 [info] Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5222 for ejabberd_c2s
```