# .sh script that executes command as "real" root

Tags: sh, root, sudo, ejabberd

I want to write a .sh-script that sends a message to my ejabberd-account. (the script is "called" by the apache2 standard-user "www-data").

The script should execute the following command: `ejabberdctl send_message chat admin@my-domain user@my-domain "title" "my message"`

However, I can't run any ejabberdctl command without "being" root. So `sudo ejabberdctl` is not working (in terminal or any .sh-script). I can only do `sudo -s` followed by `ejabberdctl my-command`, which doesn't work in .sh-scripts (or am I wrong?).

(I've installed ejabberd 20.07 on ubuntu 20.04 with the help of this tutorial: [Install Ejabberd...](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu/))

Is there a way to run a command in a .sh-script as "real root" or to create a root-session and run the command there (like I do manually with `sudo -s ...`)?

Is there any solution to my problem or should I install ejabberd the "normal way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why I can only run `ejabberdctl` when I'm "logged-in" as **root** (`sudo ejabberdctl` is still not working)

Is my .bashrc file wrong? (last line: `PATH=$PATH:/opt/ejabberd-20.07/bin/`)

Anyway, at least I can run `sudo /opt/ejabberd-20.07/bin/ejabberdctl my_command` with any user, like they did here: [Ejabberd sbin/ejabberdctl start (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300202/14261923)

Has someone else experienced this weird behavior with `sudo: any_command: not found` ?

Let me know if you have a more "elegant" solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When ejabberd is compiled and installed from source code, it's possible to prepare it with something like

```
./configure -–enable-group=ejagroup
```

Then, you can simply create the system group `ejagroup`, and add the `www-data` user to that `ejagroup`.
See https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/installation/#options

In your case, that you use the Debian package from ProcessOne, I see the tutorial mentions that you create a system account called `ejabberd`. Maybe you can run ejabberdctl from that account, no need to be `root`?

Comment: If I try `sudo runuser -l  ejabberd -c '/path/to/my_script.sh'` I still get an error: `ejabberdctl: command not found`. I think it has to do with the `bashrc` file.